# KEA File Conversion using gdal_translate

Tags: remote-sensing, geotiff-tiff, gdal-translate

I was using ARCSI (Atmospheric and Radiometric Correction of Satellite Imagery) to atmospherically correct data, the default output format is KEA ('kea'). I'm trying to convert these to 'tif' format using this gdal statement (`gdal_translate -of GTIFF LS8_sref.kea reflectance.tif`), but was getting an error message (too many command options).

Are there alternative ways to convert kea to tif or any raster format?

@AndreJ - This is the file:https://www.dropbox.com/s/kdy80qggdgufum5/LS8_20140927_lat50968500lon5287500_r28p19_rad_sref.kea?dl=0

Comment: Are you using proper dash? It can be problem with keyboard layout. In question looks you are using (hyphen, linker – ) not a just dash (-). Keyboard layout error are the main reasons for such errors

Comment: @Bulva. Seems it worked! I used a dash now, but then got another error message. The error message however seems to be with using different version of HDF5: Warning! ***HDF5 library version mismatched error***
The HDF5 header files used to compile this application do not match
the version used by the HDF5 library to which this application is linke

Comment: I am glad to hear it. I hope we will solve the next error

Comment: Are you using windows, Mac or Linux?

Comment: I am using Linux (ubuntu)

Comment: Why don't you export GeoTiff format from ARCSI as it is also using GDAL? It should be possible using `--format Gtiff` (see http://rsgislib.org/arcsi/scripts.html#arcsi-py).

Comment: @danclewley I should have spotted that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Windows OS, some GDAL builds from Gisinternals are compiled with the KEA driver as well, see

http://www.gisinternals.com/packageinfo.php?file=release-1800-x64-gdal-2-1-0-mapserver-7-0-1.zip

---

**UPDATE**

The [KEA driver](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_kea.html) needs a GDAL version 2.0 or later. The linked file works well with the gisinternals build of GDAL 2.1.0, and the resulting tif seems to be placed in the right spot:

[image]

gdalinfo reports: `Driver: KEA/KEA Image Format (.kea)`.

Loading the file directly into QGIS 2.14.3, the HDF5 driver is used, but the result is misplaced in Ecuador. My QGIS version is not build with KEA driver support.

Unfortunately, the ubuntugis unstable build of GDAL 2.1.0 does **NOT** (yet) include the KEA driver. So you have to compile GDAL yourself to get the KEA support for Linux systems.  For furher support on that, see https://bitbucket.org/chchrsc/kealib/wiki/Building%20KEA%20on%20Ubuntu

You will definitely run into further problems, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/702145/c-header-files-for-hdf5-are-missing

Copying missing files to the expected folder, or adding folders to search paths will clear the situation, and finally I got Ubuntu Xenial to run GDAL 2.1.0 with the KEA driver:

```
 gdalinfo --formats | grep KEA
 KEA -raster- (rw+): KEA Image Format (.kea)
```

gdal_translate now creates the same output under Ubuntu as the Windows build does.

Comment: I'm glad you made it work! Could you please explian more on how use the gisinternals build of GDAL 2.1.0 to do this (or can it be implemented in linux too - I use ubuntu). I can do it in windows too anyways. Also, how can I build my QGIS with KEA driver support, if that will remain the only solution.

Comment: See my extended answer.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to install the KEA driver for most platforms (Linux, OS X and Windows) is by using conda and installing binaries from the conda-forge channel.

First download and install Miniconda from http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html

Then install GDAL (which is built with KEA support) from the conda-forge channel using:

```
conda install -c conda-forge gdal
```

You should then have GDAL with the KEA driver, you can confirm by running:

```
gdal_translate --formats | grep 'KEA'
```

Comment: @ danclewley. I will definitely do try this!